# Is it possible to get the ClientDetails in TokenEnhancer

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've configured some additional_information in the oauth_client_details table which i need to send as a additional data in access token response.

Tried calling `OAuth2AccessToken.getAdditionalInformation()` which is giving empty

Also can somebody explain the use of

```
Map<String, Object> getAdditionalInformation() in org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
@Component
public class ClTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    public ClTokenEnhancer( ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService ) {

        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance( OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication ) {

        ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId( authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId() );

        ( (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken ).setAdditionalInformation( clientDetails.getAdditionalInformation() );

        return accessToken;
    }
}
```